# Google scripts - Formatting date from a form input

Tags: date, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

To preface I'm very new at this but I currently have a script that outputs a Google Doc/PDF based on inputs into my google form.

The PDF is output whenever a new form is submitted, currently the formatting for the date comes out as DD/MM/YY but I want it to appear as dd MMMM yyyy i.e. 19 May 2020 rather than 19/05/20.

I've tried using the following to change the formatting

> ```
> var signDate = e.values[1];
> var formatSignDate = Utilities.formatDate(signDate, "GMT+1", "dd MMMM yyyy");
> body.replaceText('{{Execution Date}}', formatSignDate);
> ```

But I get the following error

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.
>   at autoFillFromForm(Code:17:28)

What am I doing wrong? Can I not use .formatDate with the date from my sheets cells?

Edit: error message with log of signDate

> Stackdriver logs Info signDate = 20/05/2020 Error Exception: The parameters
>   (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for
>   Utilities.formatDate. at autoFillFromForm(Code:23:34)

Answer (score 1):

### Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate

means that `signDate` is not recognized correctly as a date object

Please provide a log of `signDate` to help you troubleshoot more in detail.

### UPDATE

If you have a date string in UK format ( DD/MM/YYYY), it won't be automatically recognized as a [Javascript date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

You'll need to convert it, e.g:

```
  var convertedDate = new Date(signDate.split('/')[2], signDate.split('/')[1] - 1, signDate.split('/')[0]);
  Logger.log(convertedDate);
  var formatSignDate = Utilities.formatDate(convertedDate, "GMT+1", "dd MMMM yyyy");
  Logger.log(formatSignDate);
```

Note: Using `Utilities.formatDate()` as above might give you the wrong date if you are setting it to a different timezone than your script time zone.

Comment: thanks, when I log signDate I get this:
Info signDate  = 20/05/2020

Comment: The problem is the UK timezone, have a look at my updated answer.