# Change date format which going in mail but it showing an error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, date-formatting

I have tried `Utilities.formatDate` but it showing an error

> Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate.

```
function findCell() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("DELEGATION");
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(5,1,lr-4,9).getValues();

  for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < dataRange[i].length; j++) {     
      var taskAsignDate = dataRange[i][0];
      var taskId = dataRange[i][1];
      var doerName = dataRange[i][2];
      var taskName = dataRange[i][4];
      var dueDate = dataRange[i][5];
      var taskAsignBy = dataRange[i][6];
      var date = new Date;
      var status = dataRange[i][1];
      var htmlfile = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("email")
      htmlfile.taskAsignDate = Utilities.formatDate(taskAsignDate,"GMT","dd-mm-yy");
      htmlfile.taskId = taskId;
      htmlfile.doerName = doerName;
      htmlfile.taskName = taskName;
      htmlfile.dueDate = dueDate;
      htmlfile.taskAsignBy = taskAsignBy;
      htmlfile.status = status;
      var htmlforemail = htmlfile.evaluate().getContent();
      if (dataRange[i][j] == "Pending" && doerName == "Mr. Deepak Raj" && dueDate<=date) {
         Logger.log(dataRange[i],[j]);
         GmailApp.sendEmail("abc@abc.com","Test HTML","HTML FILE",{htmlBody:htmlforemail});
      }
    }    
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `Utilities.formatDate` should be a Date object, but the value of `taskAsignDate` is a string.

You need to review your spreadsheet and verify that the values of first column from the source range (`sheet.getRange(5,1,lr-4,9).getValues()`) are all dates.

Related

- [Google scripts - Formatting date from a form input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61889116/1595451)

Comment: I already have checked the same all date columns are in date format

Comment: The error messsage says  that at least one value of the first column, starting on row 5,  is not a Date object. Edit the question to describe the relevant parts of the spreadsheet structure, add sample data and describe how you verified the data type  of the first column.